# Cant get jQuery variable to work

Tags: jquery

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with this code? For some reason my `uiop` variable won't work...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var siteUrlValue = 'http://www.dagbladet.no/';
    console.group('Initializing Google URL Shortener API...');
    $.urlShortener({
        longUrl: siteUrlValue,
        success: function (shortUrl) {
            var gooGl = shortUrl;
            console.info('The Short Url is: ' + gooGl);
            console.groupEnd();
            setTimeout(function () {
                asdf();
            }, 5000);
        },
        error: function (err) {
            console.error(JSON.stringify(err));
            console.groupEnd();
        }
    });

    function asdf() {
        var uiop = gooGl();
        console.info('The Short Url is: ' + uiop);
    }
});
```

Pleas see example on [jSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iamchriswick/qmvvu9vu/1/)

Comment: `gooGl()` is not defined (check your console).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it's because your function asdf() don't know about variable gooGl. Second, gooGl() is function and not a variable.

Try this:

```
setTimeout(function () {
            asdf(gooGl);
}, 5000);

function asdf(gooGl) {
    var uiop = gooGl;
    console.info('The Short Url is: ' + uiop);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You declare gooGl inside of the successfuntion of the Ajax call. That means it is not handled over as global variable for your asdf function to use. You have to hand it over via parameter.

Plus you call gooGl() instead of gooGl, which means that the content of the gooGl variable is not returned as a variable type, but as a function call.